# Am I misunderstanding MVC3 ModelBinding - NHibernate interaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I'm using nhibernate & MVC3.
I have two simple models and a view model that contains a few properties of it's own + one for each of the models.

e.g.

```
class Contact() { ... }
class Address() { ... }

class EditContactVM() { 
    public string something {get;set;}
    public Contact contact {get;set;}
    public Address address {get;set;}
}
```

All the base models implement an interface (IMyModel) which has an Id property and a few other bits.

I have a generic model binder that pulls the Id from the data posted back by the view and gets the object from the database:

```
public class NHibernateModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder where T: IMyModel
{
    private DataAccessService DataAccessService { get; set; }

    public NHibernateModelBinder(DataAccessService dataAccessService)
    {
        DataAccessService = dataAccessService;
    }

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult IdResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Id");
        IAgBiTechModel model = null;
        if (IdResult != null)
        {
            model = DataAccessService.Get<T>(Convert.ToInt32(IdResult.AttemptedValue));
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

and a model binder provider that creates the appropriate binder for the type.

This all works perfectly, I end up in my controller with an EditContactVM object populated with the properties appropriately populated from the database.

However, there is one thing that's confusing me:
As I understand it, after the model binder does it's thing and gets the entity from the DB, the properties of the object should be updated with the values posted back from the view.

e.g. I'm editing contact with Id 5.
The contact name is updated from 'James' to 'Tom' on the view.
On post back, the model binder will grab contact 5 from the DB and assign this to EditContactVM.Contact.
--- Now I expect MVC to update EditContactVM.Contact with data from my view. i.e. By the time I get to my controller, EditContactVM.Contact.Name will be 'Tom'.
Instead, I just get the unmodified DB object and lose the data posted back by the view.

THe only other thing I can think of that might be relevant is that the EditContactVMBinder looks like this:

```
public class ContactVMBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private Func<ContactVM> EmptyViewModelFactory { get; set; }

    public ContactVMBinder(Func<ContactVM> emptyViewModelFactory)
    {
        EmptyViewModelFactory = emptyViewModelFactory;
    }

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = EmptyViewModelFactory();
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Edit: Added a bit of view markup

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Contact", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.contact.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.contact.Timestamp)
    if (Model.address != null && Model.address.Id > 0)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.address.Id);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.address.Timestamp)
    }

    <div class="row">
        <h4>Contact Details</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.contact.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field row">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contact.FirstName)
        <span style="margin: 2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.contact.FirstName)
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Where's your view and controller code? You've told us everything but the important bit! Can you see the changes in your controller or are you only looking at the DB result?

Comment: @Liam The controller code is not relevant - it's the object that gets passed to the controller from the binder that is the problem. I've added part of the markup for the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding BindModel you are effectively telling the framework not to do "its thing" and that you will bind the model yourself.  You have to call super.BindModel() for the framework to bind the data from the view to the instance it creates for you. Another approach would be to override OnModelUpdated(), at that stage the framework has created you an instance of your model and populated it with the data from the view (same result can be obtained in BindModel after calling super.BindModel), you can then update that instance with whatever you want to retrieve from the database.

Comment: That's what I suspected. However, the ContactVMBinder already calls base.BindModel(..). For the NHibernateModelBinder, I don't think I can call base.BindModel because I can't see a way to pass it the object that I've grabbed from the DB. i.e. I could call it and it would create a Contact object using the data from the view but it would not be the DB object that was modified and I'd have to manually do the update in my controller. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Found the answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I just needed to replace the return Model; line in NHibernateVMBinder with 
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = model;
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);